# hackerrank.com find-hackerrank solution on Obj-C

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to solve https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/find-hackerrank on Obj-C, and get ok output via xCode, but not via hackerrank's "Run Code" button.

xCode output:

[image: http://monosnap.com/image/SBZTETlf6WjEiNPr50zpYQ7G119wC7]

hackerrank output:

[image: http://monosnap.com/image/9WApf0Q5ptYAkN7Oc1ipw9tBBauSJA]

So it is at leat strange to see different outputs.

my code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main()
{
    NSFileHandle *input;
    NSData *inputData;

    NSString *match = @"hackerrank";
    int amount;
    NSString *str;

    input = [NSFileHandle fileHandleWithStandardInput];
    inputData = [input availableData];
    amount = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:inputData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] intValue];

    for (int j = 0; j < amount; j++)
    {
        inputData = [input availableData];

        str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:inputData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];

        NSArray *redexArr = @[match,
                              [NSString stringWithFormat:@"^%@.+", match],
                              [NSString stringWithFormat:@".+%@$", match]
                              ];

        for (int i = 2; i>=-1; i--)
        {
            if (i <= -1)
            {
                printf("-1\n");
            } else
            {
                NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", redexArr[i]];
                if ([pred evaluateWithObject:str])
                {
                    printf("%d\n", i);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I saw the screen shot, but I wasn't able to get to a screen like that when I tried your code on their site. Where did you click to see that output?

Comment: Just copy my code from this page, open find-hackerrank page. That set obj-c and paste my code to the "current buffer" http://monosnap.com/image/FLectpUOjQgpfLzO9cevVgCiXLLZoh Than tap "Run Button" and see http://monosnap.com/image/IN14tr3tNkdUViBcb7K2BKFxr24c96

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference between the run in Xcode and on HackerRank is that when you run locally, the call to

```
[input availableData];
```

stops when your program have read the next line from console. This lets you call `availableData` multiple times, each time getting the next line.

On HackerRank, though the very first call of `availableData` gets the entire file, leaving nothing to the rest of your program to consume.

You can fix this problem by reading the file line-by-line, or reading the entire content, and splitting it on end-of-line markers.

Here is your fixed submission that passes all tests on HackerRank:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main()
{
    NSFileHandle *input;

    NSString *match = @"hackerrank";
    int amount;

    input = [NSFileHandle fileHandleWithStandardInput];
    NSArray *inputData = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:[input availableData] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] componentsSeparatedByString: @"\n"];
    amount = [inputData[0] intValue];

    for (int j = 1; j <= amount; j++)
    {
        NSString *str = inputData[j];

        NSArray *redexArr = @[match,
                              [NSString stringWithFormat:@"^%@.+", match],
                              [NSString stringWithFormat:@".+%@$", match]
                              ];

        for (int i = 2; i>=-1; i--)
        {
            if (i <= -1)
            {
                printf("-1\n");
            } else
            {
                NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", redexArr[i]];
                if ([pred evaluateWithObject:str])
                {
                    printf("%d\n", i);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Merc I am not sure if you can get it to run inside Xcode in the same way as it's being run on hackerrank, but you should be able to run it locally from command line and get the same results as they do. It looks like the difference between the two ways of running it is that Xcode's input console does not make all the input available to your program at once, waiting for `\n` before feeding it the next chunk.

Comment: xCode and terminal variants are the same for your code. http://monosnap.com/image/3KtPhy7GtQPlOiMxo1hLQlg8LHuS5w but really it passes all the hackerrank cases. So hackerrank trouble solved, but still unable to run this code on local mashine

Comment: @Merc It looks like you are pasting the input file into the console window when running my code on the terminal. That's not the right way - you should paste the input into a file, and use input redirection `./a.out <test-input.txt` to have the program read directly from the input file.

Comment: Solved by puttind console app (hackerrank) and text file with input (test.txt) to the one folder and run in terminal from this folder: "./hackerrank <test.txt"